# Joomla good PDF viewer

Tags: pdf, joomla, module

I'm searching for a good PDF viewer for Joomla, the problem is when there is a module in an article all the PDF viewers I tried so far show: {loadposition myposition} in place of that module.

Does anybody know a PDF viewer that will show the module.
I would also like it to have a header and footer option.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your extensions 'might' not be the sole source of your troubles.

Have you installed "Modules Anywhere" from nonumber.nl?

I recommend you try that first before assuming that the problem lies in your extensions.

Here is the appropriate link: http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/modulesanywhere

Install it, and make sure the editor plugin is also installed and enabled (Modules Anywhere may perform these steps upon installation), then open up the content item you wish to inject your module into and use the module selection tool provided to you by the editor plugin.

After you perform this test, you can more reliably assume that your PDF related modules are the culprits.

Good luck!

Comment: Thx for your answer, I fixed the PDF problem with a different code. But I used the "module anywhere" for an other problem I had.